# one firebase database to two diff apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two Android project1:1.qaai_admin 2.qaai, I want to send data from app no 1 to firebase and retrieve that data by app no 2,in this I need both the app sharing same firebase database, how can I do that?

Comment: I have added an answer. Have a look at it. :)

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

**STEPS TO DO THIS:**

1. Go to your Firebase Console
2. Select Home Tab
3. Click on Add App
4. Select Add Firebase to your Android App
5. Provide the details for the Package Name
6. Download the latest Config File
7. Add the downloaded Config File to both the Android Apps